# "Press any button to continue" in Visual Studio Express C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-prompt

When creating an console application (blank document) how can I get the "Press Any Button To Continue" to automatically show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it manually with a 
`system("pause");`

*Be carefull, this is not [portable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) (will work on windows, but might not work elsewhere)

Comment: Is there some kind of setting that does this by default?

Comment: If you are debugging your application (using F5) it will. If you want it to be done event when you are not starting your application from visual studio, I don't think so. You have to add it manualy. This is a behavior that you are adding to your application, you must program it.

Comment: @Drahakar You are correct, it doesn't work in Linux. However, the code will still compile and will simply say command not found at the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a console program in the IDE using "Start Without Debugging" (`Ctrl-F5`) you get the behavior you're looking for.

For some reason, when you start the program in the IDE under the debugger ("Start Debugging" or plain-old-`F5`) you don't get that prompt when the program ends.  If you just want to be able to see the last bit of what's in the console window when run under the debugger, you can set a breakpoint on the `return` from `main()` (or the closing brace for `main()`).

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin function. However you can do a simple loop with kbhit() and getch(), like so:

```
#include <conio.h>

void main( void )
{
    // Display your message here

    for(;;)
    {
        while( !kbhit() );
        if (getch() == 0x0D)
            break; // Break on ENTER
    }

    // Continue on here
}
```

Adapted from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/44895

Comment: I would downvote this, but I don't think `void main` is a legitimate reason for a downvote.

Comment: @Etienne: Haha, its definitely not the best practice. However since I don't have Visual C++ installed (I use GCC), I simply copied the declaration from support.microsoft.com/kb/44895 I'm going on the assumption that VC++ will work with Microsoft's own code. I'd rather have less-than-desirable code quoted from the official source, than submit my own code without testing it on that compiler.

Answer (score 0):

system("pause") is definitely what you were asking for, but using it is very bad practice. Consider just using cin.get() at the end and press enter.

Comment: This is true. Using a `std::cout<<"Press Any Button To Continue"<<std::endl;` and  `cin.get()` would be the most portable way.

Comment: @Drahakar Indeed, although I can understand that people like to use system("pause"), it makes your intentions more obvious that cin.get().